# Shopify's Dashing List widget not refreshing correctly

Tags: listview, refresh, dashing

Recently I've noticed that my dashboard's list tiles do not refresh as expected. Refresh time was set to one hour (both as '60m' and '1h'), yet it tends to get blocked until dashboard's restarted with refresh set to 1 second.

The list I'm using is actually a copy of basic List widget adding up to 8 data columns:

```
<h1 class="title" data-bind="title"></h1>
<p class="more-info" data-bind="moreinfo"></p>
<ul class="list-nostyle">
  <li data-foreach-item="items">
    <span class="label" data-bind="item.label"></span>
    <span class="value-list-details" data-bind="item.value1"></span>
    <span class="value-list-details" data-bind="item.value2"></span>
    <span class="value-list-details" data-bind="item.value3"></span>
    <span class="value-list-details" data-bind="item.value4"></span>
    <span class="value-list-details" data-bind="item.value5"></span>
    <span class="value-list-details" data-bind="item.value6"></span>
    <span class="value-list-details" data-bind="item.value7"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
<p class="updated-at" data-bind="updatedAtMessage"></p>
```

This is the only thing changed except for class names where needed (*.coffee and *.scss), this said *.coffee file looks the same as basic list:

```
class Dashing.List_details extends Dashing.Widget
  ready: ->
    if @get('unordered')
      $(@node).find('ol').remove()
    else
      $(@node).find('ul').remove()
```

There are no errors visible in Chrome's console. It's not browser related as in all, Opera, Firefox, IE and Chrome the issue is visible, so it seems to be backend related.

The 'last update' also doesn't change and stays at last hour it worked.

Did anyone encounter this problem or has any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is how Dashing works. The first refresh will kick in after 1h, since you set the refresh rate to 1h.

If you dont want to see the last snapshot remove the history.yml before restarting dashing. This will cause the dashboard to show blank data.

Another way to do it is to set the values before the scheduler kicks in, so it refreshes first and then waits until the scheduler pushes the data.

If you can, get the data every 1h but send the even every minute.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself very clear up there. It doesn't refresh even for a day, despite 1h refresh setting.